# Matlab Regexp - make sure there is no extra at the end of string

Tags: regex, matlab

I am using Matlab's `regexp` to try to compare strings.

My data has multiple signals, and I am trying to match those signals to certain strings. My problem is that some of the signals that match my string have extra characters at the end, so I don't want to match with those signals.

An example of how my data is formatted is:

```
signalA_1
signalA_1_extra
signalA_2
signalA_2_extra
...
signalA_99
signalA_99_extra
...
signalB_1
signalB_1_extra
...
signalZ_1
signalZ_1_extra
```

I want to match with `signalA_1` - `signalA_99`, but don't want `signalA_1_extra` - `signalA_99_extra`.

I have tried something like:

```
for i = i:length(signals)
  sig = signal(i)
  if startsWith(sig, 'signalA')
    if regexp(sig, 'signalA_\d*[^\.]+')
      store signal
    end
  end
end
```

I have also tried:

```
regexp('signalA_[\d]*^.')
regexp('signalA_[\d]+[^\.]')
regexp('signalA_\d\d^.')
```

and others.

Also, I think I can eliminate the `startsWith` step too and just use one expression.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Edit:
Also it could potentially be a one or two digit number. Is \d+, [\d]+ or \d* the correct form?
Also note that I only want signalA_1-99. Not signalB-Z.

Comment: Try [`(?m)^signalA_\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/a0rMdi/2).

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I've created an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/a0rMdi/2)

```
(?m)^signalA_\d+$
```

- `(?m)` Enable multi-line mode (`m` flag). This allows `^` and `$` to match for each line (not just the start/end of the file)
- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `signalA_` Match this literally
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

The following would filter your list of values down to the things you care about (based on your example data).

```
filterOut = count(signals,"_") > 1;
signals(filterOut) = [];
```